# Fastest way to read millions of integers from stdin C++?

Tags: c++, file, sorting, io

I am working on a sorting project and I've come to the point where a main bottleneck is reading in the data. It takes my program about 20 seconds to sort 100,000,000 integers read in from stdin using `cin` and `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` but it turns out that 10 of those seconds is reading in the data to sort. We do know how many integers we will be reading in (the count is at the top of the file we need to sort).

How can I make this faster? I know it's possible because a student in a previous semester was able to do counting sort in a little over 3 seconds (and that's basically purely read time).

The program is just fed the contents of a file with integers separated by newlines like `$ ./program < numstosort.txt`

Thanks

Here is the relevant code:

```
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int max;
    cin >> max;
    short num;
    short* a = new short[max];
    int n = 0;
    while(cin >> num) { 
        a[n] = num;
        n++;
    }
```

Comment: That's parsing 10M integers a second, sounds about right. Dunno if that will get much faster unless you can provide the input data as binary numbers instead of the numbers represented as text.

Comment: I have added the relevant code. I can't change the data files used to test the code, unfortunately.

Comment: ***How can I make this faster?*** Use a binary file.

Comment: Did you build in release mode?

Comment: The program is compiled with `g++ -lm yourcode.cpp` so I don't really have much freedom in terms of how anything is built.

Comment: @SnowSailor -- You are running an unoptimized build with those settings.  You're hampering yourself on purpose.  This is especially the case if the streaming operator `>>` puts in extra code or checks for validity.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately I can't change that build though. So I should remove `>>` from the while() conditional and use some other way to check for if the file is finished? Edit: I tried that and didn't get any noticeable improvement.

Comment: It isn't a matter of removing `>>`.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/g/tZyUtw)  Toggle between `-O3` and `-O0` and you will see the difference in the underlying assembly language generated (-O0 is basically what you're using now).  Seriously, it is nonsensical, at least to me, to ask for a program to "be fast", but at the same time, not allow the compiler to generate fast(er) code.

Comment: Can you read data without converting them to `int` and test pure input performance?

Comment: Reading in as strings, it takes 9.6 seconds. Converting to int as well takes about 10-12 seconds.

Comment: One final question can you check how long will take for ex. grep to search whole file `grep k < inputfile`

Comment: 0.217 seconds for the grep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get your data into memory about as fast as possible, assuming Linux/POSIX running on commodity hardware.  Note that since you apparently aren't allowed to use compiler optimizations, C++ IO is not going to be the fastest way to read data.  As others have noted, without optimizations the C++ code will not run anywhere near as fast as it can.

Given that the redirected file is already open as `stdin`/`STDIN_FILENO`, use low-level system call/C-style IO.  That won't *need* to be optimized, as it will run just about as fast as possible:

```
struct stat sb;
int rc = ::fstat( STDIN_FILENO, &sb );

// use C-style calloc() to get memory that's been
// set to zero as calloc() is often optimized to be
// faster than a new followed by a memset().
char *data = (char *)::calloc( 1, sb.st_size + 1 );
size_t totalRead = 0UL;
while ( totalRead  < sb.st_size )
{
    ssize_t bytesRead = ::read( STDIN_FILENO,
        data + totalRead, sb.st_size - totalRead );
    if ( bytesRead <= 0 )
    {
        break;
    }
    totalRead += bytesRead;
}

// data is now in memory - start processing it
```

That code will read your data into memory as one long C-style string.  And the lack of compiler optimizations won't matter one bit as it's all almost bare-metal system calls.

Using `fstat()` to get the file size allows allocating all the needed memory at once - no `realloc()` or copying data around is necessary.

You'll need to add some error checking, and a more robust version of the code would check to be sure the data returned from `fstat()` actually is a regular file with an actual size, and not a "useless use of cat" such as `cat filename | YourProgram`, because in that case the `fstat()` call won't return a useful file size.  You'll need to examine the `sb.st_mode` field of the `struct stat` after the call to see what the `stdin` stream really is:

```
::fstat( STDIN_FILENO, &sb );
...
if ( S_ISREG( sb.st_mode ) )
{
    // regular file...
}
```

(And for really high-performance systems, it can be important to ensure that the memory pages you're reading data into are actually mapped in your process address space. Performance can really stall if data arrives faster than the kernel's memory management system can create virtual-to-physical mappings for the pages data is getting dumped into.)

To handle a large file as fast as possible, you'd want to go multithreaded, with one thread reading data and feeding one or more data processing threads so you can start processing data before you're done reading it.

**Edit:  parsing the data.**

Again, preventing compiler optimizations probably makes the overhead of C++ operations slower than C-style processing.  Based on that assumption, something *simple* will probably run faster.

This would probably work a lot faster in a non-optimized binary, assuming the data is in a C-style string read in as above:

```
char *next;
long count = ::strtol( data, &next, 0 );
long *values = new long[ count ];

for ( long ii = 0; ii < count; ii++ )
{
    values[ ii ] = ::strtol( next, &next, 0 );
}
```

That is also *very* fragile.  It relies on [`strtol()` skipping over leading whitespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html), meaning if there's anything other than whitespace between the numeric values it will fail.  It also relies on the initial count of values being correct.  Again - that code will fail if that's not true.  And because it can replace the value of `next` before checking for errors, if it ever goes off the rails because of bad data it'll be hopelessly lost.

But it should be about as fast as possible without allowing compiler optimizations.

That's what crazy about not allowing compiler optimizations.  You can write simple, robust C++ code to do all your processing, make use of a good optimizing compiler, and probably run almost as fast as the code I posted - which has no error checking and will fail spectacularly in unexpected and undefined ways if fed unexpected data.

Comment: This looks neat. So this will work when you've got the file "piped" in using the `<` operator? It looks like you're getting a file descriptor. Is that related to the actual file in any way? Could you somehow use `fopen()` or something to open the file and read data that way for simplicity? And with `data` I can then write something that'll get the value on each line, convert it to an int, then load it into the array I'm storing values in?

Comment: This feels really nice. I ran it without actually parsing the integer values and it ran on 100,000,000 lines in almost no time at all. Know of the best way to parse a massive string of integers line by line...?

Comment: @SnowSailor hey I don't disagree that this is correct (fastest) solution but could you just test my last test in your environment as it should be almost as fast as this.

Comment: @SnowSailor You don't need to use `fopen()` - the redirected file is already open as `stdin`. It was passed from the parent process as file descriptor `STDIN_FILENO` - which I've never seen have any value other than zero.  The fastest way to parse a string, given NO compiler optimizations allowed, is probably not to use C++ operations. :-( C-style `strtol` should would work well - it even returns a pointer to the first non-numeric value, which can then be used to get the *next* integer value: `for(...){ long value = strtol( currPtr, &nextPtr, 0);...}` No compiler optimization is crazy.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it faster if you use a SolidState hard drive. If you want to ask something about code performance, you need to post how are you doing things in the first place.

Comment: I have added the code that I am using to read the data. I can't really change the hardware because they're the university's servers.

Comment: Shorter distance between the hard drive and the CPU?

Comment: Is there a reason why dont you directly read the file from the code?

Comment: That's a good question. The file's contents is piped into the program using the bash `<` operator. This is just how the graders are going to test the code; I can't change that. It's a shame cause I'm sure it would be much faster to have the actual file instead of the contents of it. Unless there is a way to know what the file name is whose contents is being piped in.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to speed up your program by reading the data into a buffer, then converting the text in the buffer to internal representation.

The thought behind this is that all stream devices like to keep streaming.  Starting and stopping the stream wastes time.  A block read transfers a lot of data with one transaction.

Although `cin` is buffered, by using `cin.read` and a buffer, you can make the buffer a lot bigger than `cin` uses.

If the data has fixed width fields, there are opportunities to speed up the input and conversion processes.

**Edit 1:  Example**

```
const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
char               text_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
//...
cin.read(text_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
//...
int value1;
int arguments_scanned = snscanf(&text_buffer, REMAINING_BUFFER_SIZE, 
                                "%d", &value1);
```

The tricky part is handling the cases where the text of a number is cut off at the end of the buffer.

Comment: Interesting. Can you give some brief code example for this? I'm not very experienced in C++ but what you're saying definitely makes sense. The values to sort are from 0-4000 inclusive, so your field width will be from 1-4.

Comment: A hindrance to performance is that the fields are varying width.  Because they vary, one has to search to find the end of the value.

Comment: What about using atoi instead of snscanf? ... memchr might be usable to find delimeters between fields.  To handle numbers that cross a buffer boundary, allocate 65552 for buffer size and read into buffer+16. After a read, move any partial number at the end of the buffer to just before buffer + 16. Then after the next read (to buffer + 16), start parsing at where the number was moved to.

Comment: @SnowSailor - "The values to sort are from 0-4000 inclusive", In that case, you can use a counting sort with an array size of 4001. There's no need to store the 100,000,000 integers. My previous comment explains some possible optimizations for reading the data and numbers that span buffer boundaries.

Comment: The idea for this project is that we need to write 3 different sorting algorithms. One of them is counting sort, one is insertion sort, and the other is mergesort. For all of these, I still need to get the data read in as fast as possible. Counting sort on 100,000,000 runs in 10 seconds, because it takes 10 seconds to read in the data. Like I said in my original question, the fastest counting sort algorithm ran in 3 seconds, which means that there HAS to be a way to get that data read in in 3 seconds or faster.

Comment: @SnowSailor - use buffered reads as suggested in the answer. atoi should be faster than snscanf. Insertion sort on 100,000,000 random integers can't be done in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ran this little test in compare to your test with and without commented line?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    char buffer[20] {0,};

    int t = 0;

    while( std::cin.get(buffer, 20) )
    {
 //       t = std::atoi(buffer);
        std::cin.ignore(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pure read test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    char buffer[1024*1024];


    while( std::cin.read(buffer, 1024*1024) )
    {

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without the commented line: 2.72 seconds
With: 2.83 seconds.
Not really much of a difference at all.

Comment: @SnowSailor As I made a mistake and separate number with space not new lines please do test again with fixed code. Sorry for that.

Comment: All good. Time without the commented line: 5.601s, and with: 9.160s.

Comment: @SnowSailor Can you also test with my second test?