# How do I optimise the code to return the number closest to a given integer, not present in the given list?

Tags: c++

I solved [this](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc170/tasks/abc170_c) problem statement (Yeah Yeah, I know, I am putting the problem statement below).

---

> Given are an integer X and an integer sequence of length N: p1, …, pN.
>   Among the integers not contained in the sequence p1, …, pN (not necessarily positive), 
>   find the integer nearest to X, i.e. the integer whose absolute difference with X is the minimum. 
>   If there are multiple such integers, report the smallest such integer

---

This is the code I used:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> x >> n;
    std::vector<decltype(x)> vect(n);
    bool vect_contains_x = false;
    for (auto& elem : vect) {
        std::cin >> elem;
        if (elem == x) {
            vect_contains_x = true;
        }
    }
    int num = 0;
    if (!vect_contains_x) {
        num = x;
    }
    else {
        std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());
        while (1) {
            static int i = 1;
            if (std::find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), x - i) == vect.end()) {
                num = x - i;
                break;
            }
            else if (std::find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), x + i) == vect.end()) {
                num = x + i;
                break;
            }
            else {
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << num << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This code renders the result in `13-18ms`.

---

I was able to get it down to `8-10ms` by using the following optimised code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> x >> n;
    std::vector<decltype(x)> vect(n);
    bool vect_contains_x = false;
    for (auto& elem : vect) {
        std::cin >> elem;
        if (elem == x) {
            vect_contains_x = true;
        }
    }
    int num = 0;
    if (!vect_contains_x) {
        num = x;
    }
    else {
        std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());
        auto isPresent = [=](auto num) {
            for (const auto& elem : vect) {
                if (num == elem) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
        while (1) {
            static int i = 1;
            if (!isPresent(x - i)) {
                num = x - i;
                break;
            }
            else if (!isPresent(x + i)) {
                num = x + i;
                break;
            }
            else {
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << num << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

However, the problem with both the codes (as they both use the same approach) is that,
If there is a large continuous stream of integers in the given list, something like:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...,1501

and the X given is

> 751

---

The code will need 750 iterations of the `for loop`, which is a lot. Can we use a better algorithm to find the closest integer?

---

**EDIT**:

Got it down to `6ms` by using `binary_search` (Thanks @Sebastian), but still, the algorithm remains the same...

Comment: [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) -- [std::upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound). After sorting, did you consider using those functions?

Comment: You got 10ms, but for which input ?

Comment: The time limit is 2s! So, what is your concern?

Comment: @Damien, I do not want a better time (I already have achieved really good runtime (though not as good as the guy who did it in under `5ms`)), I actually want a smarter algorithm which I could have used. At this point, the algorithm that I've used is pure `bruteforce`

Comment: Probably the slowest part is reading the data in and converting them to int. You have the possibility to use a sorted tree structure, where you can directly find the neighbouring elements, a sorted linear structure with random access (like vector) and using a binary search; or you could (as the integer is known from the beginning), check all the integers on the fly during the read, to find the closest one.

Comment: The data is implicitly converted to int (within std::cin>>), it arrives as text.

Comment: The input range is very low. We might avoid sorting. If `a` is an element of the input array, you can directly set `isPresent[a] = true` etc.

Comment: For reading in ints look at the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473560/fastest-way-to-read-millions-of-integers-from-stdin-c

Comment: The very first comment is the answer. You need ONE call to std::lower_bound and ONE call to std::upper_bound. No nested loops. If you cannot see it, imagine yourself looking for a gap (torn out page) in a book. Would you rather find page 1, then start from the beginning and find page 2, then start from the beginning and find page 3, ... or would you rather skip the "start from the beginning" part and find page 3 *starting from page 2*?

Comment: Having though about it some more, I see that you don't need two calls to these functions. You need one call to either one, to find the place in the array where your number would be. Then you run linear search from that place in both direction (like looking for a torn out page).

Comment: It depends on what number you are trying to find. To put it simply, both algorithms find the place where you want to insert your number to keep the array sorted. The difference between them is how they handle elements that are equal to the one you want to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this "cheating" algorithm. It's cheating because the `_Find_next` method is only in the `GCC` compiler. Also, with the help of `printf` and `scanf`, I accelerated input and output, due to which the program runs faster. I sent it for execution several times and received 4, 6 and 8 ms (6 ms most often):

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX_VALUES = 101;
    bitset<MAX_VALUES> bits;
    bitset<MAX_VALUES> reversed;
    bits.flip();
    reversed.flip();
    int x, n, t;
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &n);
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("%d", x);
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &t);
        bits.reset(t);
        reversed.reset(MAX_VALUES - 1 - t);
    }
    if (bits[x]) {
        printf("%d", x);
        exit(0);
    }
    int rV = bits._Find_next(x);
    int lV = MAX_VALUES - 1 - reversed._Find_next(MAX_VALUES - 1 - x);
    int d1 = abs(rV - x);
    int d2 = abs(lV - x);
    if (d1 < d2) {
        printf("%d", rV);
    } else if (d2 < d1) {
        printf("%d", lV);
    } else {
        printf("%d", min(rV, lV));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not saying that this "algorithm" is better than yours. But, as I understand it, you asked for some other solutions, this is one of the possible.

Comment: I am using MSVC. I will try to find an equivalent and try to understand the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your link, the total number of integers is at most 100.
So 100 bits are enough to hold the flags, which numbers appear in the sequence. Those can be held in the processor registers.

The following code shows only the storage, afterwords you would have to chose suitable bit scan operations:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    bitset<100> flags;
    int x = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int num = 0;
    std::cin >> x >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int elem;
        std::cin >> elem;
        flags.set(elem);
    }
    // then you can shift the result by x bits and do bit scan operations
    // there are built-ins depending on the compiler and processor architecture or the portable De Bruijn with multiplications
}
// alternatively (to the shift) you can use two bitsets, and for one set all the elements (elem - x) or for the other (x - elem)
```

Comment: @Damien: The current (half-)implementation does not depend on it